# In MS Access, how do I list records in a many-to-many relationship such that records in the table being listed are not repeated?

Tags: sql, winforms, ms-access, vba

As with most any database, in Access I can use JOIN to query a many-to-many relationship:

```
SELECT Books.Title, Tags.Subject 
FROM Tags
   RIGHT JOIN (Books 
               LEFT JOIN BookTags
               ON Books.ID = BookTags.BookID) 
   ON Tags.ID = BookTags.TagID; 


-------Books.Title--------------+---Tags.Subject-------
 Nineteen Eighty Four           |    science fiction   
 Nineteen Eighty Four           |    dystopian themes
 Freakonomics                   |    non-fiction
 Freakonomics                   |    economics
 The C Programming Language     |    textbook
 The C Programming Language     |    programming
 The C Programming Language     |    non-fiction
```

I want a form that lists each unique book only one time, with all of the authors for that book on the same line.  Something like this:

---

**Nineteen Eighty Four** -  *science fiction, dystopian themes*

**Freakonomics** - *non-fiction, economics*

**The C Programming Language** - *textbook, programming, non-fiction*

---

It would look a little different in a windows form, but you get the idea: I want only one line for each book, with the tags for that book listed out on each book's line.

I'm sure some of you are going to suggest breaking from data normalization rules, and I'm not entirely opposed to it, since this is a personal database that I use to track work that I do. (It has nothing to do with books, but books make for an easier example).  That being said, I'd prefer not to use datatypes that are proprietary to Access, in case I ever need to migrate to other software.

Comment: Right join, with left join... Most people are lost at the right join.

Comment: @jarlh In english: Return all books regardless of whether a book has a matching entry in the BookTag table

Comment: I know, but most people do it the opposite way, "major" table first. Something like Books 
               LEFT JOIN BookTags left join tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Allen Browne's [Concatenate Related](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function. Your setup works really well with the function Allen has described.

After copying the code, you can use the Query as,

```
SELECT 
    Books.Title, 
    ConcatRelated("Subject", "BookTags", "BookID = " & Books.ID) 
FROM 
    Books;
```